# How to drive a nail in a confined space?

Tags: tools, nails

I keep finding myself needing to hammer nails in places where my hammer is too long to actually make the hammer head contact the nail. This isn't a situation where I need the leverage provided by the handle - I'm choking the hammer anyway for added control and less mess should a strike slip off the nailhead - but I'd rather not saw off a good hickory handle. (And forget trying to hacksaw through a metal handle.)

What I keep wishing for is basically a metal ovoid with a flattened surface, basically a big flat hammer head I can swing with one hand. Does such exist? Or is there some other tool I should be using instead?

I've tried using a nailset, but while it's great for insetting an already driven nail, it's too finicky to get a nail started.

To provide context, I'm trying to hammer in cable staples in the space between the top of the foundation and the ceiling in a basement. That gives me a workspace of about 6 in in height, 16 in in width, and maybe 10 in in depth. With the staple inset about 5 in from the right and towards the back of the space, I can't tuck a hammer crossways into the space to swing at the nails, and the space is too deep and not high enough for me to hang the handle over the ledge and swing down.

**ETA:** Wow, thanks for the fast (and unanimous) responses! I now have an M12 battery-powered palm nailer on the way. I'm not keen on the noise and hose-dragging of a compressor, and I've got the "swap out the battery" rhythm down from using the M12 impact driver.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think what you need is a Palm Nailer.  You can get these in air or electric powered versions.  They are compact and are handy to drive nails in tight spaces.

[image: Palm Nailer]

Comment: Great minds....

Comment: Can it drive regular nails, or does it require a clip full of glued-together nails? The cable staples come with their own intrinsic nails.

Comment: It can drive regular nails and does not require a clip

Comment: These handle regular nails - you insert the nail head into the shaft - there's often a magnet within to hold it in place - position the nail where you want it and then just apply pressure and it kicks in automatically to drive your nail.

Comment: Honestly I refer to this tool as "my new best friend" now.

Comment: Looks like they're all intended to drive 2" to 3-1/2" nails (6d to 16d). Any luck using them with 1" (2d) nails?

Comment: It may be a bit fussy because the opening is a larger diameter but you should have no problems.  It will drive the nail flush.

Answer (score 12):

I saw one of these on demo at Home Depot for $49 CDN:

[image]

It's basically a vibrator that slowly drives the nail into the wood.  I tried it on a big galvanized spike, and it went in effortlessly.  However, you'll be faster using a decent claw hammer and a full swing.  This seems to fit the bill perfectly for working in places where you can't get the backswing.

If that's too pricy, I've also had some success in this scenario with one of these (Pricing unavailable.) It at least allows me to start the nail.

[image]

Comment: Late to dinner Chris :)

Comment: Yeah.  I've gotta stop typing out complete answers.

Comment: at least you used a different image :)

Comment: Hah, a version of that rock that's made out of metal and has molded grips is something I would pay money for. ;)

Comment: @JeremyW.Sherman, that'd be a [bucking bar](http://www.aircraftspruce.com/catalog/topages/buckbara.php).

Comment: @ArgentoSapiens That looks like fun. Most search results seem to assume you know what it is already. Am I correct in thinking it's held behind a rivet, so the rivet tail impacts the bar during riveting and mushrooms out to hold the rivet in place?

Comment: @JeremyW.Sherman, you got it. It's not really for hammering, but it is the equivalent of a metal stone designed for your hand.

Comment: That looks like one of the polished dung balls from Mythbusters or a Dorodango.

Comment: The head you show is 1/2 (the business end) of an interchangeable tool.  The power portion (either cord or battery) supplies the rotational  power

Comment: How do you start the nail with an avocado?!

Answer (score 10):

That problem used to plague me as well until I invested in a palm nailer:
[image]

There are also electric, cordless versions if you don't have an air compressor.

Comment: I beat you by 20 seconds :)

Comment: NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOoooooooooooooooooooooooo.................................

Answer (score 7):

Palm nailers are fantastic, I have one and use it a lot.  But for very small nails in very tight places, I like to replace the nail with a small square drive finish screw and install it with a long bit extension on my screw gun.  Quick and easy.

Comment: I bought a 12 inch Green Robertson bit for my cordless just so I could screw in the drawer locks when my kids were young.  It was so easy compared to fiddling around in tight corners.

Answer (score 4):

Palm nailers are the clear winner here, but I don't think the more low tech options have been fully explored?  Handle-less hammers are available with brand names such as "Handi-hammer" and "Thumper".

[image]